# Track Gps device location on PC/server/mobile

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, android-gps, gps-time

We are trying to build a gps tracking system and I have a confusion. GPS device dosent need internet connection that's fine but how a server or pc or mobile will know  a gps device location? PC/server/mobile has internet connection. Will satellite be able to send device location to PC/mobile if they have Internet connection? Also I want to send 4digit code along with gps location of a device is it possible to send with out Internet connection? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, you need any kind of connection.

You can not send messages through the gps system.
The satelites only send a timestamp, a gps receiver can only get the information where he is from it. GPS goes only one way.

If ur device is able to establish any kind of sattelite radio conection that will work.
Or u can use the cellphone network, wich is probaly the cheapest way to archieve what u want.